# Why is only the last occurrence being matched?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = '''
    <a class="biz-name"><span>Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken</span></a>
    <a class="biz-name"><span>South City Kitchen - Midtown</span></a>
'''
```

I am trying to match both groups between the `<span>`s

using the following

```
regex = re.compile('<a class="biz-name[\w\W]*<span>(.*)</span>')
regex.findall(s)
```

expected:

```
['Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken', 'South City Kitchen - Midtown']
```

actual

```
['South City Kitchen - Midtown']
```

Why is only the last occurrence being matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You shouldn't parse xml with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). That said, the greedyness of the regex got you, `[\w\W]*` pretty much matches anything, so it eats up the first expressions.

Adding a non-greedy `?` token (`[\w\W]*?`) fixes that. And doesn't hurt to add one in the group as well. I have replaced `[\w\W]*?` by `.*?` as it's simpler and equivalent.

```
regex = re.compile('<a class="biz-name.*?<span>(.*?)</span>')
```

See this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mTaPTE/1).

Comment: the code works. What's wrong with the comment?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest first sentence of my answer: you shouldn't parse xml with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is usually never the best way to scrape HTML. For instance, an alternative would be to use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''
<a class="biz-name"><span>Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken</span></a>
<a class="biz-name"><span>South City Kitchen - Midtown</span></a>
'''
s = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
results = [i.text for i in s.find_all('span')]
```

Output:

```
[u'Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken', u'South City Kitchen - Midtown']
```

However, a simple regex solution:

```
import re
s = '''
 <a class="biz-name"><span>Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken</span></a>
 <a class="biz-name"><span>South City Kitchen - Midtown</span></a>
'''
final_results = re.findall('<span>(.*?)</span>', s)
```

Output:

```
['Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken', 'South City Kitchen - Midtown']
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for the input, and I agree it might be a better approach but it's irrelevant to the question what the approach is. The goal is to use regex.

Comment: @cosmosa, using regex on HTML data is wrong goal

Comment: While suggesting a better way to extract that text is perfectly fine, this actually does not answer the question: *“Why is only the last occurrence being matched?”*

Comment: @cosmosa Please see my recent edit. I added a regex solution.

Comment: I like the beautifulsoup approach regardless of the fact that it's a regex question, to solve an html problem, so it's basically not ideal.

Comment: @poke Answers are not required to adhere to bad design restrictions posed by questions. Stating that they're bad and offering the better alternative is the *preferred* way to answer. As a 173k user, you should know better than to promote bad code.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, we should show the OP the best way to perform their task. However, when the OP has asked why their current code doesn't behave as expected we _also_ need to answer that question! IMHO, it's important to correct misconceptions about language features, especially when that is the main thrust of the OP's question.

Comment: @PM2Ring And that question is clearly a duplicate which needs to not be answered at all.